# How to use macros in pstricks as coordinate arguments?

Tags: pstricks

OK, as a good novice I have come across an impressive feature (the `!` symbol that allows direct injection of PostScript as coordinate arguments. I can really simplify my work with this feature so I started experimenting with it.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}%
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)%
% this works which means I could technically define points as macros
\newcommand{\pAa}{!1.5 1.5}%
\psdot(\pAa)%
% this OTOH does not work
\newcommand{\pAb}[1][1]{!1 #1}
\psdot(\pAb)%
% these don't work either
\psdot(\pAa mul 2)%
\psdot(\pAb{2})%
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}%
```

**Error message (1/47)**

> use of `\psdot@ii` doesn't match it's definition

I guess my question is twofold

- Why doesn't the later work? I'm pretty sure it has something to do with macro expansions not ocurring in the right order
- Is there a workaround for defining points and making arithmetic operations **using and passing postscript** to the *pstricks* macros?

### Update

The example works without default arguments perfectly. I welcome anyone to give an explanation as to why a default would toss the monkey-wrench

Comment: Your command definition of `\pAb` takes an *optional* argument. It therefore has the form `\pAb` or `\pAb[..]`. Is this the intent? Is it needed?

Comment: No it was not a requirement but it seemed quite handy. I have distaste of having to leave empty braces `{}`. BTW, if there isn't any defaults, it works like a charm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The construction

```
\psdot(\pAa mul 2)
```

doesn't work because spaces are ignored after control sequences, so when `\pAa` is expanded what results is

```
!1.5 1.5mul 2
```

which is illegal PostScript code. If you say

```
\psdot(\pAa\space mul 2)
```

you get what you expect.

The construction

```
\psdot(\pAb{2})
```

doesn't work for two reasons: you have defined `\pAb` with an optional argument that should be enclosed in brackets, not braces. However, also

```
\psdot(\pAb[2])
```

wouldn't work, because the definition is not “fully expandable”: its action is producing the commands for *printing* `!1 2`, not simply to those characters.

The correct definition should be

```
\newcommand{\pAb}[1]{!1 #1}
```

and calling `\psdot{\pAb{2}}` will do. No default, however: the argument is mandatory.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
%
\newcommand{\pAa}{!1.5 1.5}%
\newcommand{\pAb}[1]{!1 #1}%
%
\psdot(\pAa) 
\psdot(\pAb{1}) 
\psdot(\pAa\space mul 2) 
\psdot(\pAb{2}) 
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on: _the definition is not fully expandable_? With that info I think your answer would definetly close this case

Comment: @hanzo2001 “Fully expandable” means that no assignment is performed; a command with an optional argument requires TeX to look for the next token, in order to see if it's `[` and this is done with an assignment (`\futurelet`).

Comment: Is there any way to force (La)TeX to fully expand?

Comment: @hanzo2001 In some cases, yes. Not with a macro with a single optional argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your macros then there will be no need for the `\space`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\newcommand\pAb[1][1]{\psdot(!1 #1 )}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \newcommand\pAa{!1.5 1.5 }%  The space after 1.5 is important
    \psdot(\pAa)
    \pAb \pAb[3]%
    \psdot(\pAa mul 2)
    \pAb[2]
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, I do need `\space`. I have created simple _Point_ + **Vector** macros that can stack and be combined very easily. When one of these macros ends with a macro `\space` is a must

Comment: That depends on how you have defined coordinates with or without a space at the end.